# My Twitter api is not working suddenly

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a web application which uses twitter api. It was working fine.But suddenly it stopped work. I started googling & came to know about that twitter upgraded their api. So I need to use the library which supports v1.1

Have anybody worked with v1.1 library please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/zkniebel/jquery-twitter-feed) on GitHub. Don't be confused by the title - it has been updated since Twitter's API update to 1.1.

The jQuery plugin on the page has been re-purposed to be a Rendering engine, i.e. it helps with rendering your feeds.

The important part, however is in the "Server-Side Examples and Setup" directory. Go there, read and follow the directions in the SETUP_INSTRUCTIONS document. When you are done, if you are using PHP, use the file in the "Plug_And_Play" directory as a start point. If you are using C#, you can use [this library](https://github.com/zkniebel/TweetNet). It is still under development, but it is updated regularly and mimics the Twitter API's specifications as closely as possible.

P.S. I am the author of both of those projects, so if you need any help, let me know. Good luck! :)